# Can't install metric plugin in eclipse neon 1

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, metrics

I'm using eclipse neon.1 on ubuntu 14.04 and i wanted to install metric plug-in it  keeps saying "Cannot complete the provisioning operation.  Please change your selection and try again. See below for details."

details :
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Metrics Feature 3.14.1.201104282140 (com.stateofflow.eclipse.metrics.feature.feature.group 3.14.1.201104282140)
  Missing requirement: Metrics plugin 3.14.1.201104282140 (com.stateofflow.eclipse.metrics 3.14.1.201104282140) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Metrics Feature 3.14.1.201104282140 (com.stateofflow.eclipse.metrics.feature.feature.group 3.14.1.201104282140)
    To: com.stateofflow.eclipse.metrics [3.14.1.201104282140]

Comment: This code is old and wants to use the  `org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility` plugin which is no longer included in Eclipse. You will not get this to work with Eclipse Neon.

Answer (score 5):

Update!!
I was able to  install it  using  this new version of metrics just follow the instruction on this website http://metrics.sourceforge.net/

Comment: going to _Help Menu_ --> _Install New Software_ and adding a new remote site `http://metrics.sourceforge.net/update` did the trick. Thx!

Comment: Trinimon's answer is the right one should be featured! everything else fails! including this answer

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for Oxygen worked following the instructions in [The Metrics2 project page](http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/)

Basically,

> go to Help menu -> Install New Software ... On the opening dialog
>   click on the Add ... button. Add a new Remote site with the following
>   url http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/update/ and follow the instructions for >installation.